# Is Google chrome open source available for development?

Tags: google-chrome, open-source, developer-tools

Is there any open source version of chrome available for development on private basis means to add some features on it and release it online for other users to download it and use it. Guys can you link it.

Comment: http://www.chromium.org/

Answer (score 2):

Well Google Chrome is based in open source project called [Chromium](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/) you may be interested too in [Chrome Canary](https://www.google.es/chrome/browser/canary.html)